# How to calculate sum of an item present in multiple column?

Tags: excel, sum, sumifs

[image]

How do I add a quantity by checking its name in two columns as shown by the figure? Botsawana in column A and C should give sum result in F according to its name in E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8=E1)*$B$1:$B$8+($C$1:$C$8=E1)*$D$1:$D$8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is absolutely an answer